# Display tabitem content depending on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to display the Tab Item content depending on a property. Is it possible?

To explain, I have a another xaml which is embedded in the main xaml as below

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem" >
   <view:PaneView1 />
</TabItem>
```

Now I have another PaneView2. Depending on a condition on one inner xaml should be displayed as below

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem" >
   <!-- Condition here - if (x == true)-->
      <view:PaneView1 />
   <!-- else -->
      <view:PaneView2 />
</TabItem>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: check the condition in back-end. or bind visibility property from view-model

Comment: Where are you getting the condition from? Is it in the same page? If it is then you can go for Binding using IValueConverter. Or you can go for MVVM model to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several solution to that, the easiest one is by using a `DataTrigger` and set the Content based on you condition

```
 <TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="TabItem" >
        <TabItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <view:PaneView1 />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Content" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                    <view:PaneView2 />
                                </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabItem.Style>                    
    </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

the Condition

```
 private bool _condition = false;
 public bool Condition
 {
     get
     {
         return _condition;
     }

     set
     {
         if (_condition == value)
         {
             return;
         }

         _condition = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger to switch visibility between `view:PaneView1` and `view:PaneView2`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" Content="Edit value"/>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="You can't edit me"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="You can edit me"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MyTextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="MyTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

You can bind to any value in `DataTrigger.Binding` - either from UI or from data context (sample code is bound to UI).